# unable to semd 1000 mail from cakephp to centos(postfix/covedot)

Tags: cakephp, centos6

I am unable to semd 1000 mail from cakephp to centos(postfix/covedot).
Till 950 mails i can sent, Above that some time i lost my message boddy/email not recived by centos.
Is ther any limitation.
I also tried increase and decrease mail contents. but still getting problems.

Thank you.

Comment: any code? how yo are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is probably due to the php script taking too long to execute.  One solution is to send the emails using BCC but this isn't always an option if you are trying to track emails.  You might try sending using a less memory intensive way.  What is your current Config\email.php

Comment: Thank you :)

//current Config\email.php

public $default = array(
  'transport' => 'Smtp',
  'from' => 'no-reply@testhost.com',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => 25
 );

By this setting i can able to send mail up-to 997 users.
Is there any limitations of cakemail..?
thank you

Comment: its not really a cakephp issue.  More of a problem with php execution times.  You can send BCC which would be a little less intensive, but that might not fit your needs.